# Dynamic Nginx upstream based on ngx.var set in access_by_lua_block

Tags: nginx, lua, nginx-reverse-proxy, openresty

Simplified NGINX sample config snippet:

```
http {
  set $foo default;
  access_by_lua_block {
    ngx.var.foo = "bar"
  }

  server {
    listen 8080 default_server;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
      set $proxy one;
      if ($foo = "bar") {
        set $proxy two;
      }
      proxy_pass http://$proxy;
    }
  }
}
```

The problem I am seeing is that `$foo` doesn't seem to be set within the location block. If I add an access log that logs `$foo` under http the value will be `bar`. If I put the access log within the location block, then it is `default`.

How can I dynamically switch upstreams based on the value of an `ngx.var` set within an `access_by_lua_block`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The if statements in the location block appear to execute at a NGINX phase that happens before `access_by_lua_block`. The fix I came up with was moving the check into `access_by_lua_block`. `proxy_pass` executes in the content phase and can read variables set in the access phase.

```
http {
  set $proxy one;
  access_by_lua_block {
    ngx.var.foo = "bar"
    if ngx.var.foo == "bar" then
      ngx.var.proxy = "two"
    end
  }

  server {
    listen 8080 default_server;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://$proxy;
    }
  }
}
```

This is a really contrived example that doesn't make much sense as is, but in the real problem I wasn't simply setting `ngx.var.foo = "bar"` but instead `foo` was set based on the result of a response received from a request made within the access block, so it was much more dynamic in nature.